# Prompts the user for a word and prints all words in the file containing all characters of the word in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

For example, I have a list of words from in a file.(listed below)

```
aback

abacus

abandon

abandoned

logo

loincloth

loiter

loll
```

and some other more,a really big list of words! now the user can enter a word
for example "go", then it will show all words contain the charter `'g'` and `'o', "go", "logo", "goo"` , and so on.

And I have to make the file into a dictionary type first, I really have no idea, how to do it.

This is something I have done, I was trying to make all the words from the same letter go to together,
for example:

```
words = {'a': ['airport'], 'b': ['bathroom', 'boss', 'bottle'], 'e':['elephant']}


import operator
file = open("d1.txt","r")
words = {}
for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        first_char = line[0]
        if first_char not in words:
                words[first_char] = []
                words[first_char].append(line)
sorted_words = sorted(words.items(),key = operator.itemgetter(1))           

print(sorted_words)

user_input = str(input("Pleae enter a ward: "))
v1 = words[user_input]
print(v1)
```

Unfortunately， this is all I have done, can anyone help me out please!

Comment: Would not it be easier with regex?

Comment: I have to do it with dictionary, that is really sad. Also I am not good at it.....

Answer (score 1):

That looks somewhat strange, but anyway it will be easier to do something like this

```
 word_to_search = 'gosh' # assume that this is user input
 letters_list = list(word_to_search)
 result = []
 for letter in letters_list:
   for word in file.read().split('\n'):  #here you choose separator by which your words splitted
     if letter in word:
       result.append(word)    #here you'll get a list of all words with matching letters
```

Note that there will be duplicates, to get rid of them you can just

```
  result = set(result)  #here you will get list of only unique words
```

If you want to go with dictionary

```
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
words_list = file.read().split('\n')
words_dict = dict((letter, dict()) for letter in alphabet)
for letter in alphabet:
  for word in words_list:
       if word.startswith(letter):
          words_dict[letter].append(word)
```

This will give you dict with alphabet letters as keys and lists of words as values

Hope you can figure out how to iterate over lists in your dict.
Hint: you can join values of dict and iterate over them

Comment: yeah, as you said, I got a KeyError: 'b', I tried to put one more loop in it, I am still trying it, thank for your hint btw, at least I have something to start it.:)!